# External monitor: window/workspace off screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, workspaces

When connecting an external monitor to a laptop running Ubuntu 20.04, the "displayed screen" extends beyond the physical screen, implying that the top right of the display (containing the ubuntu menu/power-off) is not visible.

It looks like Ubuntu believes the monitor is bigger than it is? The highest resolution is offered with ratio 16:10, so could it be that my monitor is actually not 16:10? If I go for other lower resolution with different ratios, I can see the full "displayed workspace", yet those ratios are really bad and leave 30% of the screen space unused.

The available resolutions, shown by 'xrandr', together with their ratio, are:  `1680/1050` = 1.6, `1280/1024` = 1.25, `1280/960` = 1.33, `1152/864` = 1.33,
`1024/768` = 1.33, `832/624` = 1.33, `800/600` = 1.33, `640/480` = 1.33,
`720/400` = 1.8

What should I do?

Taking a screenshot to illustrate does not help much as the screenshot captures the full space, but here is an artistic attempt to explain visually:
[image]

Comment: What *Resolution* options do you see under GNOME **Settings** → **Display**?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli good point, i just added those in the question